# Will Firestore's listen function listen twice if it is run twice?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have this listen function

```
Future listening()async{
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").snapshots().listen((dodo) {
 //actins
});
}
```

and i call it by the following

```
 TextButton(
                      
  onPressed:(){
    listening();                  
  } , 
   child: Text('tab me')
   )
```

ok now i know if it been called so it will listen to events until it is canceled

but the the question is what if I tab the button twice. means i call the same function twice . Will it listen twice and cause memory leak ?  Or is that nothing to worry about?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should call a snapshot only once, otherwise firebase charges you for every ‘read’ attempt you do.

In your case, you could solve this simply by:

```
bool isListening = false;
OnPressed: (){
   If(isListening) return;
   isListening = true;
   Listening();
}
```